# Is it possible to register with eureka with Discovery first?

Tags: spring, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to achieve a **discovery first** spring cloud config mode.
This is my client bootstrap.yml

```
server:
  port: 9090

spring:
  application:
    name: test-config
  cloud:
    config:
      fail-fast: true
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        serviceId: configservice

eureka:
  client:
   register-with-eureka: true
   serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://localhost:8011/eureka/
```

The configuration is fetched ok, the client starts but is **not registered with eureka**

So when I look at the eureka dashboard i see only the config service not the client app. The documentation does not state explicitly that this does not work(if I understand it correctly).

Is this on purpose?
Is this a bug?
Is there a possibility to achieve this setup?

Comment: To add more info:
  spring-boot-starter-parent: 1.5.2.RELEASE
  spring-cloud-dependencies: Dalston.RELEASE

Also tried with Brixton

Comment: It works fine on my environment with Dalston.RELEASE. Probably there might be other problem on your env.

Comment: Would you be so kind to share your config? Maybe there is some important difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your main class include: `@EnableEurekaClient`?
Could you verify your `yml` properties are properly spaced?

Comment: I believe the register-with-eureka: true property should suffice. I also tried with this annotation but does not help

Comment: In my blog at http://tech.asimio.net/2016/12/09/Centralized-and-Versioned-Configuration-using-Spring-Cloud-Config-Server-and-Git.html#create-the-demo-config-client I covered Registration-First and Configuration-First approaches, source code is included and demo runs successfully.

Comment: I've tried your example. Downloaded config server, discovery and client. Adjusted asl little config as possible -> Same outcome. Client starts, loads the config from config server but is **not** registered afterwards.

Comment: Did you try it before "adjusting as little config as possible"? Seems that adjustment is not working properly. I would suggest to start with something that works and then change it to your needs on a step by step to find out which is messing up the behavior.

Comment: Of course I changed only the things i needed to change. The actual problem was, that in the config fetched there was a different eureka instance url. So it actually registered but to a wrong instance.
Thank you for help!